# Generate links based on whether or not a user downloaded a file

Tags: php

I need to generate a link next to a file name, based on whether or not a user downloaded that file.

So here, `$done` contains the `id` of the file that a user downloaded. It comes from a database.

My problem is, how can I assign several values to `$done` and then run the check? So `$done` will be, say, `1, 3, 5` and then run those values tru the while loop? In this case, the viewer will receive the downloded message for `ids` `1, 3, 5`

```
<?php
$i = 1;

$done = 5;//How can I assign multiple values to done and then run the check?

while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i;
    echo ($done == $i ? ' You\'ve already downloaded this <br>' : ' You have not downloaded this <br>');
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array values to $done

e.g.

`$done = array(1,3,5);` //How can I assign multiple values to done and then run the check?

Corrected Code:

```
<?php
$i = 1;

$done = array(1,3,5);//How can I assign multiple values to done and then run the check?

while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i;

    if(in_array($i,$done) 
      echo ' You\'ve already downloaded this <br>';
    else  
      echo ' You have not downloaded this <br>';

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Just what I thought of doing. And then check them using `in_array` is what you're saying? How would you suggest doing the checking in the loop?

Comment: you can use "in_array" function for checking value exists in array or not